# Mockito when same parameter with different result?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a `builder` class that has `build()` function, I'm passing a service for it.

I have a test class for the builder which has two methods

Is there a way to test the same with the same parameter twice but returning a different value?

```
@Before
public void initTest() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
private void test1{
    Mockito.when(defaultBuilder.build(service)).thenReturn(createObject());
}

@Test
private void test2(){  
    Mockito.when(defaultBuilder.build(service)).thenReturn(createDifferentObject());
}
```

The problem is I get the `createObject()` object from second test, even though I'm expecting `createDifferentObject()`.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. We must be able to copy and paste it in our IDE, and run it to reproduce the issue. What you posted isn't valid Java, and is extremely incomplete.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. These are not tests. These are just mock invocations that are never called. There is no assertion that anything happens. In newer versions of Mockito, this will just throw an exception because the mocking is unnecessary.

Comment: The point was to abstract away all the useless code, the issue is clearly described. Will edit code.

Comment: "the issue is clearly described" Are you sure about that? Two separate people have commented to say it's not clear. It is good to boil your question down to its essential elements, but you have gone too far, to the point that there is no longer enough context for it to make sense.

Comment: is your defaultBuilder annotated as @Mock?

Comment: The issue might be "clearly described", ie you get different objects between the calls, but that shouldn't happen, which is why more context is needed.

Comment: "Will edit code" ... when? It's been half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Test {

    private MyObject myobject;
    private MyObject myDifferentObject;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    myobject=createObject();
    myDifferentObject=createDifferentObject();
    }

    @Test
    private void test1{
        Mockito.when(defaultBuilder.build(service)).thenReturn(myobject);
    }

    @Test
    private void test2(){  
        Mockito.when(defaultBuilder.build(service)).thenReturn(myDifferentObject);
    }     

    }

//should work.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reset your mock before setting second value:

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#resetting_mocks

However, it is regarded as a sign of poor test concept.