# Mockito method stubbing returns stubbed value from previous test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I created a JUnit test for my controller class. Below class has two tests 1. Valid client request 2. Bad Request

I stubbed `etPeriodicSchedule.createJobSchedule()` to return different value for each test. But problem I am experiencing is, stubbed result for 1st test is returned for 2nd test as well.

Note: These tests are working as expected in Spring STS, but getting issue in Maven command line.

REST endpoint:

```
public @ResponseBody Object createJobSchedule(@RequestBody ETPeriodicJobScheduleDTO jobScheduleDTO) {
        try {
            Object obj = etPeriodicSchedule.createJobSchedule(jobScheduleDTO);
            if(obj instanceof JobScheduleDTO) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body((JobScheduleDTO)obj);
            }
            else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occured while creating job schedule", e);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(EmploymentTaxJobScheduleConstants.CREATE_JOB_SCHDL_RUN_TIME_EXCEPTION_MSG);
        }
    }
```

JUnit Test:

```
@Slf4j
public class JobSchedulerControllerTest extends BaseUnitTest {
    @InjectMocks
    JobScheduleController controller;

    @MockBean
    EmploymentTaxPeriodicScheduleService etPeriodicSchedule;

    private String etPeriodicJobScheduleJson;
    private String etPeriodicJobScheduleBadReqJson;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        Mockito.clearInvocations(etPeriodicSchedule);
        etPeriodicJobScheduleJson = createJsonString("et_periodic_job_schedule.json");
        etPeriodicJobScheduleBadReqJson = createJsonString("et_periodic_job_schedule_bad_req.json");
    }

    private String createJsonString(String filename) {
        StringBuilder jsonRequest = new StringBuilder();
        try(InputStream is = JobSchedulerControllerTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));) {
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonRequest.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while reading file", e);
        }
        return jsonRequest.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateJobSchedule() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(etPeriodicSchedule.createJobSchedule(any(ETPeriodicJobScheduleDTO.class))).thenReturn(new JobScheduleDTO());

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/jobSchedule").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(etPeriodicJobScheduleJson).contentType(contentType);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        System.out.println("==========================Printing response");
        System.out.println(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);
    }


    @Test
    public void testCreateJobSchedule_bad_request() throws Exception {
        List<ErrorResponseDTO> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        errors.add(SchedulerUtils.createErrorResponseDTO(null, "Invalid data"));
        Mockito.when(etPeriodicSchedule.createJobSchedule(any(ETPeriodicJobScheduleDTO.class))).thenReturn(errors);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/jobSchedule").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(etPeriodicJobScheduleBadReqJson).contentType(contentType);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        System.out.println("==========================Printing response");
        System.out.println(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(400, status);
    }

}
```

2nd test 'testCreateJobSchedule_bad_request()' is failing in command line, since actual the result is 200 instead of 400. can someone help what is something wrong here?

**EDIT:**

```
Please maven dependency tree below
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ scn-scheduler ---
[INFO] com.adp.scn.scheduler:scn-scheduler:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.cyber.ark:javapasswordsdk:jar:5.50.75.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] \- ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO]    +- com.carrotsearch:java-sizeof:jar:0.0.5:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.10:compile
[INFO]       \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.10:compile
```

Comment: When you say `These tests are working as expected in Spring STS, but getting issue in Maven command line`, I suspect there is no issue with the tests, but something else. How are you running the tests on CLI?

Comment: I am using 'mvn clean install' to run in command line.

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml in the question please?

Comment: I have addef 'maven dependency tree'.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown too when you run the tests on CLI or only test failure?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no exception. Stubbed result of 1st test is used for 2nd test as well though I stub the method call separately

Comment: The issue might be due to the mock. Can you try using `@Mock` of Mockito instead of `@MockBean` for `EmploymentTaxPeriodicScheduleService`?

Comment: Also, which test runner is being used by you?

Comment: seems `Mockito.when(etPeriodicSchedule.createJobSchedule` call in second Test is returning `JobScheduleDTO` instance as dictated in previous test.  try resetting `etPeriodicSchedule` by adding  `reset(etPeriodicSchedule);` before `Mockito.when(..` line in your second test method.

Comment: @sachinrai I tried reset as well, it did not help.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I tried `@Mock` , bean was not mocked so I replaced it back to `@MockBean`

Comment: pls refer my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55535175/3078394)

Comment: Thank you @sachinrai and Madhu Bhat for your quick responses. Right now I could not find actual root cause, to resolve it for now I have kept both tests in a single method. I will update this thread if I fix it

Comment: since you are using `spring-boot-test`  and `Junit 4` you need to annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest` and 
`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`,  replace `@MockBean` with `@Mock`, `@Before` with `@BeforeEach` . Also for running tests from command line you need to input command as `mvn clean test`   instead of  `mvn clean install`